# How to parse html for a specific <div>?

Tags: html, ios, dictionary, uiwebview

I'm trying to write a very simple client application for iOS to go to a website with three buttons. Each of these buttons load a different webpage and run a command in an application on the server, takes the results from that command and displays them on a map on the very same page that the button loaded.

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to do the following:

1. Click on one of the three buttons.
2. Have it then run the query.
3. JUST PULL THE DIV WITH THE MAP TO SHOW THE DATA instead of the entire page, which is what I currently have happening.

I was going to go about this by parsing the html with "libxml2" and "hpple" but I thought that I would ask here before I got started instead of spending a few days on this to realise that I am going about it the wrong way.

So with all of that said I guess my main questions are:

1. Is this possible?
2. Is the way I'm going about it correct?
   2a. If the way I am going about it is wrong, how best should I go about it?
3. Normally on the webpage the map, that I am trying to pull, updates dynamically every second or so. In order to make the map dynamic in my application will I have to poll the site every time I want the map to update? or will it automatically update?

Comment: If parsing HTML, HPPLE is definitely the way to go. See Ray Wenderlich's [How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios). I'd definitely go through the HTML first, and make sure it's not retrieving data via AJAX. BTW, have you checked the site's ToS (or in the absence of a ToS, reach out to the owner of the site) to make sure that this sort of usage of their site is permissible? Often this sort of thing is frowned upon (and they might especially object if you are constantly polling their site).

Comment: BTW, if the web site operator approves of such front-end apps, they might also be able to expose a JSON/XML interface for interacting with their servers, which will be a far more efficient and robust interface.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the feedback. Sorry for the reply but I was out of the office until today. I was actually looking at that example already! 

In regards the ToS, I think it should be fine as the site I will be polling is located on my companies network, we just have the product installed on it, so it won't be effecting them at all. Their own fron end app is open source and they openly state that you can alter it to your own requirements

Comment: Great. If you can get them to just write JSON/XML service, that would make you life _much_ easier (and it would be more robust). If not, HPPLE should do that job.